# Can I use functions as min(y,0) in ZIMPL with y being a variable?

Tags: function, variables, scip

I am using **SCIP** with **ZIMPL** to solve an optimization problem where I want to "punish" a solution for which variable *x < k*, with k being a parameter. 
 I do not want to exclude all solutions where this is the case. Therefore, I introduced variable *y= x-k* and want to add a penalty term to my objective value, but only if *y* is negative, as I don't want to punish a solution if *x>k*.

Adding `-(min(y,0))` should do the trick, but I got the feeling that all functions and operations in **ZIMPL** such as the `min` - function (listed in Table 2 and 3 on p. 7 of the **ZIMPL** documentation) can only be aplied to parameters.

Can someone confirm that? And if yes, does anyone maybe have an idea how I can implement a kind of penalty term that only punishes the negative part of variable *y* in **ZIMPL**?

PS: Sorry for the misleading tag #scip, as it is a clear **ZIMPL** related problem. But unfortunatelly there was no existing tag #zimpl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can't use this kind of operators with variables (it wouldn't be a MILP anymore). However, why don't you model it like `y1 - y2 = x-k` with `y1 >= 0` and `y2 >= 0` and then put `y2` into the objective function?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Why is it a problem that it wouldn't be a MILP anymore? the complete problem I want to solve with SCIP is already a nonconvex MINLP so I don't get why that's the reason these kind of operators cannot be used on variables. But thanks for confirming! And thanks a lot for the workaround!

Comment: It wouldn't be a problem, but ZIMPL simply does not support operators like this for variables. If you want to model an MINLP that is not a polynomial (this is supported by ZIMPL) then you should probably use another modeling language like GAMS or AMPL.